# How to group the column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where I have the user entries as in/out in a same column.

I want to group the column Direction In as a UserIn column and Direction Out as User Out column.

I want to have the SQL query to do this.

How to do this with SQL query?

[image: Actual Table ![][1]][1]]

[image: Expected Table]

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted this; I found the question clear and understandable. They were probably taking exception to screenshots of data rather than text data they could paste into a fiddle tool and play with. Worth noting for future through that people here do tend to like it if you can provide example data in text form or even better a pre made dbfiddle.com or similar so they can go straight to coding up something

Comment: @CaiusJard - its expected that people do some research and have an attempt as opposed to asking us to write their entire query for them.

Comment: @DaleBurrell I accept your point. I have tried so many possibilities where I failed to get the exact result.

Comment: @DaleBurrell the `sql` tag seems slightly different to most of SO, for me, in that regard. Frequently I find that SQL questions are typically an existing data and expected result only, and the answers provide the whole code

Comment: @naveenkumar in that case post your best attempt as part of the question (in future) - thats how things work around here :) (and don't post data in images).

Comment: @CaiusJard - there are a few people around this tag who are totally happy to just write peoples queries for them. But here has been many discussions on Meta about it, and the conclusion has always been that a question needs to show "research" which usually results in an attempt being posted.

Comment: Indeed, it would be lovely.. But I suspect that most of my answers in `sql` would be a rewrite of their efforts anyway, because sometimes they're just too far down a wrong path. I don't personally think there should be a "price of admission" to SO that allows us to demand X and Y and Z from newbies by default; if they've provided X and Y, it's enough - the questions will get better over time if we can encourage them to stick around. Sometimes feel it's like standing on the beach and telling the sea to retreat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fa06's answer is(was; now deleted) how I might approach a pivot normally but you have a slightly different situation in that you want to preserve all the rows and that answer will only retain the last login and out by a user

So long as in and out are reliably written you could:

```
SELECT
 userid,
 indate,
 indir,
 case when nextdir ='out' then nextdate end as outdate,
 case when nextdir ='out' then nextdir end as outdir
FROM
(
 SELECT
  userid,
  logdate as indate 
  direction as indir,
  lead(logdate) over(partition by userid order by logdate) as nextdate,
  lead(direction) over(partition by userid order by logdate) as nextdir
 FROM
  table
) x
WHERE indir='in'
```

In the inner query we use the LEAD function to retrieve the values of date and direction for the "next" row for each user. "next" is defined as "the row with the timestamp that is immediately after the current one". Hopefully for every in row this will be the corresponding out row but it might not, if we get two in rows in sequence.

Anyway, so once we have our result set added to with every IN row having the next OUT values in it, and every out row having the next In values we just remove half the rows by WHERE indir = 'in'. This will remove half of the rows but that's ok because we took the data we wanted from those rows and brought it into the rows we are keeping with the LEAD operation

It's also a good opportunity to check that the out data really is out data and that's what the case when does. If two in rows occurred in sequence then the nextX columns would have IN data in them, not outdata, so we just null it by not providing any case for if they contain IN data

Note that is said "reliably written" earlier because this method could go wonky if you have multiple rows with identical time stamps and the db chooses to order the out row before the in row. In this case you could consider adding the direction to the order by so the in sorts before the out. Only you will know if this is necessary

Comment: Two things missing. Outdir is not mentioned in the inner query and last filter should be on indir instead of indate.

Comment: @Caius Jard what if an out time is missing, will it be just empty cell ?

Comment: It will indeed just be an empty cell. If two out times occur in a row only the earlier one will be assigned to an in time. The later one will be "lost"

Comment: @CaiusJard it is empty cells only. Thanks

Comment: @naveenkumar is your comment a report of a bug in the query?

Comment: @CaiusJard it is not bug

Comment: just checking, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can try below way-

```
select a.userid,a.logdate as userid,a.direction as direction_in,b.logdate user_out,b.direction as user_out
from
(
select userid,direction,logdate from tablename where direction='in')a
inner join 
(select userid,direction,logdate from tablename where direction='out')b
on a.userid=b.userid order by a.logdate,b.logdate
```

Comment: That will kill a lot of the result rows though

Comment: Grouping on user ID won't work. If you look at question, so same user id, it is asking for in and out time.

Comment: @ManuGupta,really??

Comment: Try running it. It will give max timestamps. Not each in and out time for same user.

Comment: @ManuGupta, thank u

Answer (score 0):

This query provide what you want

```
select UE1.UserId,UE1.LogDate, UE1.Direction, 
(select top 1 UE2.LogDate from UserEntries UE2 where Direction = 'out' and UE2.LogDate > UE1.LogDate order by UE2.LogDate),
(select top 1 UE2.Direction from UserEntries UE2 where Direction = 'out' and UE2.LogDate > UE1.LogDate order by UE2.LogDate)
from UserEntries UE1
where Direction = 'in'
order by UE1.LogDate
```

Comment: this really works and gives me exact result, thanks @Hadi. I just want to try it out with other conditions

Comment: Performance of this one could be quite poor; check the plan carefully

Comment: yeap, i compare your query with my query, your query completely betther than my query. thanks dude

Answer (score 0):

You may try this.

```
; with cte as (
select row_number() over (partition by Direction, UserId order by Logdate) as Slno,
 DeviceId, UserId, logDate, direction from table1
)
select i.Userid, i.logate as [User In], i.direction, o.logdate as [User Out], o.direction
from ( select * from cte where direction = 'IN') as i 
inner join ( select * from cte where direction = 'OUT') as o
on i.Userid=o.Userid and i.slno=o.slno
```